# Put references in a separate pages

Tags: cross-referencing

I am writing a scientific paper with maximally 5 pages, where the the 5th page contains references only. How can I put the references in a separate page? thanks

Comment: `\clearpage` before `\bibliography{}`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the easiest way is to use `\clearpage` before your bibliography.
This is better than `\newpage`, as it prints all the figures and tables before adding the bibliography on a new page.

Comment: \newpage worked for me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

`\clearpage` is definitely working for me. When I use `\newpage` or `\pagebreak` in some instances they do not work at all but `\clearpage` always works.

Comment: I can also confirm that, `\newpage` does not work with the acm latex templates.